# How can I safely discard local changes in Plastic SCM?

Tags: version-control, plasticscm

I have a little experience with Git and Atlassian Source Tree. I've just joined a team using Plastic SCM and I'm gently prodding my way around their project, seeing how parts relate to each other.

I'm VERY keen not to commit / push changes to their codebase until I know exactly what I'm doing, so I'm looking for a failsafe, straightforward way to discard my local changes. I'm currently working my way through the documents, but it'd be lovely if someone could point me in the right direction here, as I'm trying to get up to speed fast...!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 options:

1. Undo the changes, completely discarding them.
2. Shelve the changes, creating a temporal headless changeset that can be reapplied later from any other branch.

Both options are available in the pending changes view of the PlasticSCM client.

Comment: I would also say a 3rd, but less likely option is to create your own branch and mess in there.